# xsl:include template with no default namespace causes xmlns=""

Tags: xslt, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I've got a problem with **xsl:include** and default namespaces which is causing the final xml document contain nodes with the **xmlns=""**

In this synario I have 1 source document which is Plain Old XML and doesn't have a namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SourceDoc>
    <Description>Hello I'm the source description</Description>
    <Description>Hello I'm the source description 2</Description>
    <Description/>
    <Title>Hello I'm the title</Title>
</SourceDoc>
```

This document is transformed into **2 different** xml documents each with **their own default namespace**.

First Document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OutputDocType1 xmlns="http://MadeupNS1">
   <Description >Hello I'm the source description</Description>
   <Description>Hello I'm the source description 2</Description>
   <Title>Hello I'm the title</Title>
</OutputDocType1>
```

Second Document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OutputDocType2 xmlns="http://MadeupNS2">
   <Description>Hello I'm the source description</Description>
   <Description>Hello I'm the source description 2</Description>
   <DocTitle>Hello I'm the title</DocTitle>
</OutputDocType2>
```

I want to be able to re-use the template for **descriptions** in both of the transforms. As it's the same logic for both types of document. To do this I created a template file which was **xsl:include**d in the other 2 transformations:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="Description[. != '']">
        <Description>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </Description>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now the problem here is that this shared transformation **can't** have a default Namespace as it will be different depending on which of the calling transformations calls it.

E.g. for First Document Transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="SourceDoc">
        <OutputDocType1 xmlns="http://MadeupNS1">

            <xsl:apply-templates select="Description"/>
            <xsl:if test="Title">
                <Title>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
                </Title>
            </xsl:if>
        </OutputDocType1>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:include href="Template.xsl"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This actually outputs it as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OutputDocType1 xmlns="http://MadeupNS1">
   <Description xmlns="">Hello I'm the source description</Description>
   <Description xmlns="">Hello I'm the source description 2</Description>
   <Title>Hello I'm the title</Title>
</OutputDocType1>
```

Here is the problem. On the description Lines I get an **xmlns=""**

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first xslt, which contains the literal result element `Description` has no default namespace. This element is therefore in no namespace, and is being explicitly rendered as such via `xmlns=""`.

Section 6.2 of [Namespaces in XML 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#defaulting) says that:

> The attribute value in a default
>   namespace declaration MAY be empty.
>   This has the same effect, within the
>   scope of the declaration, of there
>   being no default namespace.

In order to control the namespace generated in the included stylesheet you will need to pass the namespace-uri through to its templates, using a variable or param.

```
<!-- in the included stylesheet -->
<xsl:template match="Description[. != '']">
    <xsl:element name="Description" namespace="{$output-namespace}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!--
    and add this to your First Document Transformation stylesheet
    as a top level element under xsl:stylesheet
-->
<xsl:variable name="output-namespace" select="'http://MadeupNS1'"/>
```

Comment: Can you explain how that could be done with a variable? I did try that myself, however the calling templates couldn't update the variable name.